# glassfish file descriptor recommendations

Tags: java, glassfish

on glassfish v 3.0.1, I use to get a `too many open file` exception raising after a while. The file descriptor limit is set to `1024` for the glassfish user that launch the server. I wonder if there is a recommended file descriptor limit to avoid this annoying exception. Just met me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, there is no "universal" value, it depends on things like the host(s), your app, the number of clients...

In the [Chapter 5 Tuning the Operating System and Platform](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19879-01/820-4343/abeir/index.html), they show how to set it to 8192 on Solaris which seems to be a reasonable first step.

See also [Thread: "Too many open files" error in Linux](http://forums.java.net/jive/message.jspa?messageID=473178).

Comment: Thanks, we will try various configurations and if it stable will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

The link in Pascals reply is dead. Go to [File Descriptor Settings](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19159-01/819-3681/abeja/index.html) for how to do this on Solaris. It's pretty straightforward, just remember that if you make the change using ulimit alone, the change doesn't persist.

Also the jvm option [-XX:+MaxFDLimit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) might be what you want, but again appears to be Solaris specific. I haven't tried using this particular option.